# can't find tensorflow in spyder which already installed. An old and new question

Tags: python, tensorflow, spyder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5SKt.jpg)I knew this is an old question but my version is a little different. I installed tensorflow in python 3.10 and it showed in pip list, but when I tried to import it in spyder, it showed ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'. I tried all the solution in stackoverflow and didn't work for me....

I already added the pip show pip location(which is a site-packages named folder) into the PYTHONPATH MANAGER but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try the `python -m pip install tensorflow` one? If `spyder` uses a different version of `python` than `pip`, that would cause this issue, and that command might solve it.

Comment: Thank you so much! My spyder is 3.8 and python is 3.10. That solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. I think this happens to a lot of us.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.